# a graphic utility in windows to change folder/file permissions like chmod in linux

Tags: windows, chmod

i want to make a folder available for upload to users.
i have to make this folder as 777 file permissions
Is there any graphic based software to accomplish this task ?

Answer (score 1):

Windows does not use the Linux permissions system. You can change the permissions on a file by right clicking it, selecting Properties, and choosing the Security tab. You will likely need to read up on NTFS permissions in order to understand the options there. Basically, in Windows each file can have different permissions for multiple users and groups, unlike in Linux where each file has just one user and one group with permissions different from the "everyone" byte.

Comment: Most Linux filesystems have ACLs.

Comment: Yes, but they're very infrequently used, so most Linux desktop users are unfamiliar with them.